# open a popup window when the previous window remains in background - asp.net

Tags: asp.net, background, popupwindow

I want to open a new aspx page when a button pressed by the user that use the app.

until now I used `Response.Redirect` but now I want that the previous page will stay in the background, and that the new popup will present only table data, **without postback.**

Does it possible?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be a button?  If it's just a link then you can set its `target` attribute to open the URL in a new window (or tab, it's up to the browser).  Something like this:

```
<a href="popup.aspx" target="_blank">click here</a>
```

If it has to be a button, then you can [open the new window with JavaScript](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jwinopen.htm).

But there's really no way for the server-side code to tell the browser to open a new window.  It all has to translate on the client-side in the end because the browser is the part that's opening the window.

On a side note, for better UX you might want to consider using something like the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) instead of a pop-up.  It's not only nicer from the user's perspective but I find that it's easier from a development perspective because it allows you to keep your pop-ups for a page on the page itself, so you don't have to worry about the exact issue you're facing now.

Essentially you'd load your pop-up's data (either on page load or by AJAX when it's called) into a hidden `div` and just show that `div` to the user when they click a button.  The jQuery UI plugin just styles it nicely for you and handles modality and things like that.

Comment: thanks for your answer. let's say that I use the href option how can I pass the user parameters (e.g userName and password) to the new page?

Comment: @OfirAN: Why exactly do you need to?  If the page is in the same web application then the user would still be using the same session, wouldn't they?  So you'd track on the server who that user is.  If the user is authenticating in this action then you'll want to handle the authentication in a standard POST request before doing any redirecting or anything like that.

Comment: First, it has to be a button. Second, what exactly I want is when administrator user push the button, a popup window which contains table data would appear. now I have 3 buttons like that and each button should show diffident table. maybe with jQuery UI Dialog it should be easier, does it?

Comment: @OfirAN: If that's all then you definitely don't need to send credentials over the wire for that.  The administrator(s) should already be logged in when they see the buttons.  With the jQuery UI Dialog it would probably be a lot cleaner and easier.  The tables can just be loaded onto the page and shown/hidden on the client-side, removing the need for unnecessary page requests and pop-ups.

Comment: You're right. I already done that with GridView. First, all the tables is hidden. But the problem is when the user push the button, all the previous data in the page is vanish and the table is shown. I want to show the data without previous data will disappear. Can I do this or I should use jQuery UI Dialog for it?

Comment: @OfirAN: What causes the data to vanish?  You should just be able to add an HTML button (no need for an ASP.NET Button control) and bind some JavaScript code to its Click event to show/hide the divs containing the corresponding tables.

Comment: I need your help. How can I open dialog with jQuery UI Dialog? I tried some examples and it didn't work. please if you can help me.

Comment: @OfirAN: That's worth posting a new question.  Make sure to include the code you're using, a link to the example you're following, etc.  It shouldn't be difficult, but it's better done in the standard question/answer format than in a comment thread.

Comment: Last thing. how can I execute code behind function on html button push?

Comment: @OfirAN: I thought the point of this was to avoid a post-back?  One approach without a full page refresh would be to use jQuery to make an AJAX call to a web resource.  I generally like separating those out into HttpHandlers, but there are several ways to do it.

Comment: If I do this with html button it cause post back?

Comment: An HTML button only posts if/where you tell it to.  An ASP.NET button posts back to the page by default.  If you're going for a JavaScript approach, especially with AJAX, then I'd recommend the HTML button so you'd have more manual control over it's behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ModalPopupExtender in the Ajax Toolkit. This will allow you to open a dialog on the page without a postback, and with the parent page in the background.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/modalpopup/modalpopup.aspx